# A Boolean function returning a value

Tags: javascript, typescript

Well, I am studying some code and wonder about this function, I know it is a boolean, but I have this before and wonder exactly how this syntax works.
Is it supposed to ask if a wall exist or not exist and return true?

```
hasVisited(): boolean {
    return (
      !this.northWall || !this.eastWall || !this.westWall || !this.southWall
    );
  }
```

Comment: We don't have the full code (where did you take the function from?) so I can only guess that `this` is referencing some kind of tilemap cell? If that's the case you're looking at a function that returns true if at least one of the sides is not walled off.

Comment: There are 4 walls. If any one wall doest exist(or true) it returns true.

Comment: @VK321 That's incorrect. If at least one does not exist, return `true`...

Comment: What the code might be doing is checking whether any of four walls are visited, this is done by checking if any of the object's properties has a value or not. [Refer this](https://javascript.info/logical-operators#not)

Comment: If this returns true- At least one side has no wall at all. If this returns false- all the sides have walls.

Comment: We still don't have context for whether `this.northWall`, etc. refers to whether `this` has a wall in that direction, or if that direction/wall has been visited from `this` already.

Comment: @Romen as the method name is 'hasVisited` I guess it is about visitors and not about walls. But it's too late for me to edit. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Prasanth Ganesan, It would be nice to see more of the code since we also can't be sure that the function's name is relevant to its actual behaviour. Poorly named functions are easy to come across! The best we can do is provide an answer like Avin Kavish's that focuses on the boolean logic itself without interpreting what those wall properties represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This translates into return true if `northWall` is not truthy or if `eastWall` is not truthy or if `westWall` is not truthy or if `southWall` is not truthy, else return false.

Which translates into return true if `northWall` is falsy or if `eastWall` is falsy or if `westWall` is falsy or if `southWall` is falsy, else return false.

Which translates into return true if any of the `(north|south|east|west)Walls` are falsy, else return false.

Comment: "truthy" and "falsy" would be more accurate terms to use in this case.

Comment: yeah I thought about that, I should probably edit that in.